# VS2008/ASP.NET 3.5 - How to create dynamic webforms

Tags: asp.net, dynamic, visual-studio-2008, webforms

The question in a nutshell: Is there a way to add forms dynamically to a aspx-page? I know how to add controls to an existing form, but how to add a whole form?

Bckground:

I am "forced" to work in Visual Studio 2008 and I want to create a controller, which builds a page depending from the list of elements a model gives it (e.g.: the list may contain a paragraph, an image, another paragraph, a parapgraph again, **a form** and so on).
This works fine for the first examples as I am able to add them to the inner-html of a div-container.

Thinking about ways to generate a form like this (innerHTML += form), I feel I'd be throwing the few possible advantages ASP I can see (compared to PHP) out of the window in terms of input validation and so on. But I can't find a way to generate a "real, server-run" form. The same goes for gridviews, but I guess the solution may be similar.

A possible workaround would be to create an empty form

`<form runat="server" id="dummyForm">...`

and add controls to it dynamically. The obvious(?) downside to this would be, that I couldn't change its position (at least I wouldn't know how) in relation to the other content elements. 
Another downside would be that I would be limited to one form per page and that may or may not be sufficient. If it wasn't I would starting to add several empty dummy-forms and would start indexing them and all of that doesn't look very cool to me.

Is there a more elegant way to a solution?

TIA

Simon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't add more than once server side Form tag in single aspx file 
   (in run time or design time)

maybe this article help you to generate dynamic forms :

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479330.aspx

Comment: Thank you for your feedback.
I've learned that there is no solution, but it is still a valid answer and I am getting used to it concerning ASP.NET. ;)